# Combining different dataset of columns as a full csv datat frame

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform

I took a dataset from UCI's repository using the mvlearn package to access the data. With this data, I want to obtain one CSV file as a data frame so that I can use it for machine learning models.
This is how I loaded the data

```
from mvlearn.datasets import load_UCImultifeature
# Load entire dataset
full_data, full_labels = load_UCImultifeature()
```

The variable named full data has five columns, and full labels gives us the label column. Now I want to combine them into a csv file where I will have six columns in the one csv file.
The description of the data can be found on this [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/multiple+features).

I want to use the data set to perform PCA, then apply cluster analysis and use it for supervised machine learning models like discriminant analysis.

1. How do I get the dataset as one csv file? or
2. How do I use such data extensions for PCA, cluster analysis, and the SML model?

Ideas on either of the above are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the dataset doesn't have 5 columns.

> This dataset consists of features of handwritten numerals (`0--9`) extracted from a collection of Dutch utility maps. 200 patterns per class (for a total of 2,000 patterns) have been digitized in binary images. These digits are represented in terms of the following six feature sets (files):
>
> 1. mfeat-fou: 76 Fourier coefficients of the character shapes;
> 2. mfeat-fac: 216 profile correlations;
> 3. mfeat-kar: 64 Karhunen-Love coefficients;
> 4. mfeat-pix: 240 pixel averages in 2 x 3 windows;
> 5. mfeat-zer: 47 Zernike moments;
> 6. mfeat-mor: 6 morphological features.

As you can see the description. These are separate files that have different columns. They only have the same number of rows (2000).

Let's cut to the chase, this code is what do you want.

```
from mvlearn.datasets import load_UCImultifeature
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Load entire dataset
full_data, full_labels = load_UCImultifeature()

print([full_data[i].shape for i in range(6)])
# [(2000, 76), (2000, 216), (2000, 64), (2000, 240), (2000, 47), (2000, 6)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(full_data[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(full_labels, columns=["target"])

concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(concat_df)
```

In this case, I just only dealt with the one file of the list. So, if you want to concatenate others as well, you can do this by following:

```
for i in range(1, len(full_data)):
  df = pd.DataFrame(full_data[i])
  concat_df = pd.concat([df, concat_df], axis=1)

print(concat_df) 
#2000 rows × 650 columns
```